# Solution sets of an inequality in three variables.

Tags: inequality

Determine if the following inequality holds for any set of non-zero real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ :

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge 4(ab+ ac+bc)$$

My approach: Since the question requires us to determine the possibility of the solution set, providing even one solution set should suffice. I have set different conditions like $a<0$ and $b>0$ but haven't been able to find a solution set. I am probably doing this the wrong way. Searching for similar equations tells me it has something to do with the volume of elliptic cones. Please guide me in the right direction for solving such questions. Conversely, is this inequality invalid for all non-zero reals and is a=b=0 and c>=0 the only solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Clearly not, since
$$1^2+1^2+1^2=3<12=4(1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1)$$

Comment: I think proving that it doesn't hold for a=b=c=1 doesn't make this inequality invalid. The question asks for at least one solution set.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what your question was. But I can say that the inequality you wrote is not valid for all numbers. That is, if the inequality does not satisfy any of the numbers within the given condition, then this inequality is not true. If you need to find numbers that satisfy this inequality, those numbers are too thin. For example: |$a=x$|$b=x+1$|$c=x+2$| $\iff x \in \left[ \frac{-3-\sqrt{6}}{3},\frac{-3+\sqrt{6}}{3}\right]$

Comment: Hmm. Could you please expand on what you did in the last part? And is that a solution to the inequality?

Comment: $$x^2+(x+1)^2+(x+2)^2 \ge 4\left[x(x+1)+x(x+2)+(x+1)(x+2)\right]$$
$$3x^2+6x+5 \ge 4(3x^2+6x+2)$$ 
$$3x^2+6x+5 \ge 12x^2+24x+8$$
$$3x^2+6x+5- 12x^2-24x-8 \ge 0$$
$$-9x^2-18x-3 \ge 0$$
$$3x^2+6x+1 \le 0$$
$$3\left(  x-\frac{-3+\sqrt{6}}{x} \right)\left(  x-\frac{-3-\sqrt{6}}{x} \right) \le 0$$
$$\left(  x-\frac{-3+\sqrt{6}}{x} \right)\left(  x-\frac{-3-\sqrt{6}}{x} \right) \le 0$$ 
$$ x \in \left[ \frac{-3-\sqrt{6}}{3},\frac{-3+\sqrt{6}}{3}\right] $$

Comment: This is just one example of the set that satisfies the given inequality

Comment: So this proves that this inequality holds for "some" non-zero reals, right?

Comment: $$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: $$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

Comment: Taking any one (say $c$), negative and with large enough absolute value, will give such cases.  If you want positives only, make any two, say $b, c$, small enough and the remaining $a$ much larger than $4$ to get innumerable such examples.

Comment: The inequality can be seen as a quadratic function of $a$: ${a}^{2}+ \left( -4\,b-4\,c \right) a+{b}^{2}-4\,bc+{c}^{2} \ge 0$.